# Syntax:Error JSON.parse, When trying to load data for protovis

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, protovis

Hi I'm learning how to work with protovis, so far so good, but now I stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to solve.

The following is the code. (*I have the latest jquery loaded in my headers*)

```
<script type="text/javascript+protovis"> 
var dataURL = "http://eagereyes.org/media/2010/protovis-primer/earthquakes.json";

var JSONdata = $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: dataURL, async: false }).responseText;
var earthquakes = JSON.parse(JSONdata);

var width = 560;
var height = 245;

var barWidth = width/earthquakes.length;
var gap = 2;

new pv.Panel().width(width).height(height+5)
    .add(pv.Bar)
        .data(earthquakes)
        .bottom(0)
        .width(barWidth-gap)
        .height(function(d) d.Magnitude * (height/9))
        .left(function() this.index * barWidth)
    .root.render();
```

When I try this in Firefox i get this alert:

```
Syntax:Error JSON.parse
```

I have validated the JSON on http://www.jsonlint.com/ already. So the problem must be elsewhere.

Anyone knows whats going on here?

**Edit**

I tried loading the same data in the protoviewer app: http://www.rioleo.org/protoviewer/  and it works. So it must be the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a regular async callback instead of the synchronous approach?  Like:

```
var dataURL = "http://eagereyes.org/media/2010/protovis-primer/earthquakes.json";

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: dataURL,
  success: function(response) {
    var earthquakes = JSON.parse(JSONdata);

    var width = 560;
    var height = 245;

    var barWidth = width/earthquakes.length;
    var gap = 2;

    new pv.Panel().width(width).height(height+5)
        .add(pv.Bar)
            .data(earthquakes)
            .bottom(0)
            .width(barWidth-gap)
            .height(function(d) d.Magnitude * (height/9))
            .left(function() this.index * barWidth)
        .root.render();     
  }
});
```

Also, is that JSON file located on the same server that the page making the request shows in the address bar (exactly `http://eagereyes.org`)?

Finally, the manual JSON.parse() step isn't necessary.  If you add the `dataType: 'json'` parameter, $.ajax() will automatically deserialize as JSON and uses JSON.parse() where available.

Comment: Thanks!! That didn't gave me the error anymore. Though nothing seems to be loaded. I don't know if that JSON is located on the same server.

Comment: When I said same server, I should have said same domain.  Is the page with this JavaScript on it accessed via some URL beginning with `http://eagereyes.org`?

Comment: That leaves you in a difficult position.  You can't use the regular AJAX methods that use XMLHttpRequest for cross-site requests; the browser will forbid those requests for security reasons.  If you have control of the remote site, look into making that data available as JSONP.  If not, you'll need to build a server-side endpoint that fields requests from your $.ajax() code and acts as a proxy for requesting that remote data and returning it back.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot. That answers it for me. So basically what I need to do in order to make this work is get the JSON loaded from the same domain. Would sub domains work too?

Comment: Actually file_get_contents()  (in php) could be a solution here!

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? Some browsers don't define the `JSON` object. You can download a script from the URL below which will define the `JSON` object if it doesn't already exist.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

You can check whether `JSON` is defined as follows:

```
alert(JSON);
```

**update**

OK next thing I'd do is check that the ajax call is actually returning the corect data. Change your code to print the JSON returned from the ajax call.

```
var JSONdata = $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: dataURL, async: false }).responseText;
alert(JSONdata);
var earthquakes = JSON.parse(JSONdata);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Firefox(Latest) and I also checked in Safari. The alert(JSON) gave me this : [object JSON]

Comment: Alright, thanks again. The first one with the alert(JSONdata) gave me an empty alert, then the error. The second one only the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semi-colon `;` to the end of your response

Comment: Where? I'm sorry I don't see it. I have been string at this code for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveChangesInEditing.php",
            data: idObject,
            success: function(data){
                         dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
                         $("input[name = 'id']").val(dataObject.id);
                         $("input[name='full_name']").val(dataObject.full_name);
                         $("input[name='sport']").val(dataObject.sport);
                         $("input[name='idol']").val(dataObject.idol);
                    },
            error: function(data){
                     alert("error!" + data);
                   }
        });
```